# T-SQL logic idea needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hey guys again your expertise is highly needed here..
A customer visits a bank, an agent helped him with his account.Again the same customer comes back gain in the same day and another cashier helped him/her.So there is a record of those two or more vists.But only one should be counted.
this was the way I was thinking about doing it but it doesnt help me solve it..HWta do you guys think..as usual your input is greatly appreciated..."OBVIOUSLY I AM LOST"..thanks guys.....

```
     SELECT  CD.MEMACT,
                 CD.DATETIME,--DATETIME
                 CD.AG_ID,
                 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                                   CD.MEMACT,
                                   CD.DATETIME,
                                   CD.AG_ID
                            ORDER BY CD.DATETIME)RANKED

             FROM MEM_ACT_TBL
             WHERE CD.MEMACT='1024518'
```

Comment: what r u trying to achieve?

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want only the last visit? What database platform are you using?

Comment: if a customer visits a bank and someone assists that customer, it means some kind of entry is made. SO you need to ensure that no duplicate entry is made.

Comment: post involved tables structure and examples of initial data, and data you want, please

Comment: sql server..is what i am using..I am trying to take out those unnecessary visits out of count..I want only to count those significant visits..lets say if he deposits 20 dollars and takes out 20 back again..its not necessary..he didnt do nothing..I dont exactly need that ..so it may have been done by one agent or he might have used two agents....

Comment: how do you determine which ones are significant?

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you mean, and your example is rather unfortunate: both customers and banks care a lot about every payment and withdrawal transaction, even if the net result is zero. It would help if you show some sample data and explain what the results should look like. You only need to show some simple dummy data to explain the point, it doesn't have to be real data. I suspect you are "lost" because you haven't fully understood the requirements yourself, although I may be wrong.

Comment: There is a table that would identify transactions.We could join to that table through Memact.So when a transaction occurs it has a flag.So a person could come to tha bank twenty times and we want to count those transactions which have effect..so if flag is from N to Y and  Y to n ..nothing happend..so I want to exclude from counting this transactions.I hope this helps...Thanks again guys..

Comment: It might help someone else, but I still don't understand what you're asking: I have no idea what your data looks like or what you consider a "transaction which has effect". Instead of describing your problem, please post some sample data and the expected results, that will be a lot clearer than trying to explain it in words.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * 
from
         (
         SELECT  CD.MEMACT,
             CD.DATETIME,--DATETIME
             CD.AG_ID,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                               CD.MEMACT
                        ORDER BY CD.DATETIME)RANKED

         FROM MEM_ACT_TBL
         )
WHERE RANKED = 1
      AND MEMACT='1024518'
```

that should get you the first record.  Change Order By to `CD.DATETIME DESC` if you want the last record